# Can log4net appenders be defined in their own XML files?

Tags: log4net

I want to define a handful of (ADO.NET) appenders in my library, but allow users of my library to configure the use of those appenders.  Something like this seems to be what I want:

```cs
XmlConfigurator.Configure(appenderStream1);
XmlConfigurator.Configure(appenderStream2);
XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

But that doesn't seem to work, in spite of the debug output containing messages like this:

> Configuration update mode [Merge].

What is the right way to do this?  Or, is there an alternative to asking users to duplicate large chunks of XML configuration?

**Solution:**
Thanks to Stephan's suggestion, I was able to implement the following log initialization method.  It first reads the .config section into an `XmlDocument` and then adds external appenders (which are in my case embedded resources) to the document, finally feeding the whole lot to log4net.

```cs
static readonly string[] AppenderConfigs =
{
    "Logging.EntryPointAppender.xml",
    "Logging.TracingAppender.xml",
    "Logging.MessagesAppender.xml",
};

public static void Initialize()
{
    // this first bit reads the log4net config in the application's config file
    var section = (XmlElement)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("log4net");
    if (section == null)
        return;
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    using (var xml_reader = new XmlNodeReader(section))
        xml.Load(xml_reader);

    // then we augment the above XML with the content of our embedded resources
    foreach (var appender_config in AppenderConfigs)
        using (var stream = EmbeddedResource.Open("My.Assembly", appender_config))
            AddToConfig(xml, stream);
    XmlConfigurator.Configure(xml.DocumentElement);
}

static void AddToConfig(XmlDocument config, Stream xmlStream)
{
    var fragment = config.CreateDocumentFragment();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(xmlStream))
        fragment.InnerXml = reader.ReadToEnd();
    config.LastChild.AppendChild(fragment);
}
```

Comment: You should make your solution an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following:

- read all xml fragments
- combine them yourself (with linq or whatever) to a valid log4net configuration "file" (in memory of course)
- feed that to log4net

Comment: Bah, I forgot to return to this question after implementing your suggestion!  I've editing the resulting code to appear in my OP.  Thank you!